# How to make output into list within list format?

Tags: list, python-3.x, matrix

I have written this program that takes a list of lists (matrices to be exact) and returns the values below the diagonal numbers from top left to bottom right, as `0s`.

```
def matrix(t):

    s = len(t)

    for i in range(s):
        for j in range(s):
            if j >= i:
                print(t[i][j], end='')
            else:
             print(0, end='')
        print()

t = [[2,6,8],[9,4,5],[7,2,4]]
```

The current (clean) output is as follows:

```
268
045
004
```

I want the output to be in list within list form (less simple and uglier) like the input:

```
[[2,6,8],[0,4,5],[0,0,4]]
```

I have tried `print(t)` which printed the clean output & the original list. Makes sense.

I have tried `print(list(t))`. Which, again, gave

```
268[[2, 6, 8], [9, 4, 5], [7, 2, 4]] 
045[[2, 6, 8], [9, 4, 5], [7, 2, 4]] 
004[[2, 6, 8], [9, 4, 5], [7, 2, 4]]
```

I have tried `print(list(t)[i][j], end='')` but that still gave me the clean output. If anything, I was hoping it would just give me the original list (`t`) and then I could play around with that and see where that leads me. But that never happened.

I know I need to make a new m and we'll just call it `new` for now. But 1, do I really need to make a new variable `new` and give it its "calculation", for lack of a better word? Couldn't I just move some things around in the original code? 2, if I did make a `new` variable, how would I implement that?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the loop with `print(list(t))` or have you tried adding `print(list(t))`? The latter would definitely cause what you're seeing.

Comment: If you're not concerned too much about memory, why not make a copy of t, modify it in your loop and then just print the copy?

Comment: @TinyT I have tried that but no luck. I end up getting that block up there in the OP.

Comment: @Maciek Yea no that will complicate things and memory is taken into account. I want the simplest code possible given the current conditions.

Comment: glibdud answered it below.

Comment: @adhamncheese Actually it was a question for clarification (what you have done to get the "double" output above), not a suggestion - or rather, if the latter is what you did, the suggestion would have been to remove the single-element output in your loop. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TinyT ahhhh no worries. After long hours of working with this stuff, nothing makes sense in the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, all you need to do is actually update the appropriate elements of `t`, rather than printing them:

```
for i in range(s):
    for j in range(s):
        if j < i:
            t[i][j] = 0
```

This will update the object that you passed in to the function as `t`, changing it in the outer scope. If that's not what you wanted, you'll need to make a deep copy of the list and use that instead.

Comment: Updated. But now when I run the program, I get empty spaces below it. Basically getting nothing. So there should be a return or a print somewhere in your loop. But print("what?") exactly is the question.

Comment: @adhamncheese `print(t)`?

Comment: But okay, I put a `print()` under the `t[i][j] = 0` and a `print(t)` under the `if j < i:` following the `print()` and it listed out 12 lines of results. I want to say it's trying to outlie the steps. The first 3 are a pointless repetition of each other. Unaltered. Then we see a space and then 3 more the same with the first `0`. Then space then we see an extra 0. Then the final 2 lines with the correct `0s`. All I want is that last line

Comment: @adhamncheese I'm unclear on what you want. If you just want to see the end result, why are you putting `print` statements in the loop? Why not just a `print(t)` at the end of the function?

Comment: I see it now. My apologies. I guess I was just going off of my original code and assumed I needed a print statement within the loop. So I took that out and left the print statement at the end of the function and it clicked! Thank you!